# Listing Android Bluetooth devices

Tags: android, listview, bluetooth

This is totally in sane, I got my app working 100% (it's only listing devices not doing any connection) but when i execute it it doesnt appear any Bluetooth device in my ListView, the funniest part is that when I execute it with debugger they DO appear. Here you have my code, I have been looking at it for the last 3 hours, hope you can land me a hand :(

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ListarDispositivos extends ListActivity {
    //this, R.layout.activity_listar_dispositivos, s

    private BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mNewDevicesArrayAdapter;
    private static String EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS = "device_address";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listar_dispositivos);

        mNewDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.nombres_dispositivos,R.id.txvNombreDispositivo);

        ListView listview = getListView();

        setListAdapter(mNewDevicesArrayAdapter);
        //listview.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);   

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

        mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        doDiscovery();

        Intent discoverableIntent = new
                Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
                discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
                startActivity(discoverableIntent);


    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // Make sure we're not doing discovery anymore
        if (mBtAdapter != null) {
            mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }

        mBtAdapter.disable();

        // Unregister broadcast listeners
        this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);

    }

    private void doDiscovery() {

        // Indicate scanning in the title
        setTitle("Escaneando");

        // If we're already discovering, stop it
        if (mBtAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }

        // Request discover from BluetoothAdapter
        mBtAdapter.startDiscovery();
                Toast toast1 =
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Estoy buscando", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                toast1.show();

    }

    private OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // Cancel discovery because it's costly and we're about to connect
            mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            // Get the device MAC address, which is the last 17 chars in the View
            String info = ((TextView)v).getText().toString();
            String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

            // Create the result Intent and include the MAC address
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS, address);

            // Set result and finish this Activity
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    };

    //Salta cada vez que encuentra un dispositivo o eso deberia el cabron

    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already
                if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                }
            // When discovery is finished, change the Activity title
            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {

                setTitle("Elija dispositivo");
                if (mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
                    String noDevices = "No encontrado";
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
                }
            }
        }

    };


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.listar_dispositivos, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

After adding found devices to the `mNewDevicesArrayAdapter`, you should call `notifyDataSetChanged()` so that the listview is refreshed.

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't work, the problem is that when I try it on debugger devices are listed, otherwhise they're not... Anyway thank you for the quick answer :)